# Excel on Mac - conditional formatting only works until other condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel's driving me crazy again... I'm trying to do conditional formatting with 3 conditions - Yes should be green, No should be red and any other text should be yellow. For this, I have (please note that I ***do not actually have the Stop if true fields ticked***, I was just trying to make it work, but it didn't help so I switched it off):

[image]

and for yellow:

[image]

However, the yellow condition *only works until I type either Yes or No in a field*:

[image]

And then if I either type Yes or No, the yellow rule stops working:

[image]

Why on Earth is this happening? Why does Excel hurt so much? How can I fix this?

Comment: There's no need to respond to something like that; I flagged his comment as unfriendly/unkined. Either a moderator removed it, or he removed it himself.

Comment: @lte__   I wasn't dissing you, I was given the same advice myself, and I found it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly the below may work for you.

[image]

The condition I used for orange is:

```
=AND(D1<>"",D1<>"No",D1<>"Yes")
```

Not sure how you want to handle blanks, or if you want to handle numbers separate from text values or not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that my experience is entirely in the Windows-based version, so if the Mac version has any inexplicably different behaviors, it may just be Mac-version-strangeness. That said, I can't think of any reason why conditional formatting would function differently across platforms.

---

**Start by changing `Show formatting rules for` to let you see everything.** You want to make sure you don't have any competing/erroneous conditions that could be messing up the ones you're working with.

**Your formulas should not have ranges in them.** When working with conditional formatting, Excel will evaluate them relative to the "Applies to" range<sup>1</sup>.

```
=NOT(OR(D2="Yes",D2="No"))
```

If the above is combined with an `Applies to` that starts with cell `D2`, it will check `D2` to highlight `D2`, `D3` to highlight `D3`, and so on. The formula you're using tries to evaluate the entire range, shifted down once for each row. That definitely isn't what you want.

**You need to use the `Stop If True` function or arrange your formulas in the right order.** The conditional formats are applied in order. That means whichever formula comes *last* is the one that will take precedence.

In this example, it's the Windows version and we're starting with A1 instead of D2, but the logic is the same. Sadly, the column widths aren't adjustable in this window, but I assure you that the yellow formula is logically equivalent.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

---

You can even do things like highlight multiple cells based on a single column using static references<sup>2</sup>. For instance, if you used `$D2` instead of `D2` and an `Applies to` that extended into Column `E`, it would reference `D2` when evaluating for `E2`, because the column reference is locked/static.

That said, your red one should show similar problems to the yellow one. I'm not sure why it does not. You should be able to do that one with cell-value-is-equal-to<sup>3</sup>. In fact, your green one should be an "equal-to", not a "contains", unless you can guarantee the entry will never have a "yes" anywhere in it.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I generally like to use full ranges (`Applies to` of `D:D`) for my conditional formatting, and suppress it in the heading row with either `ROW() > 1` in the specific conditional formatting, or a separate conditional format that just covers the heading row and uses the "Stop if true" functionality to suppress later conditional formats.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>I mention this, because when highlighting cells as you're doing, I often like to tie in an `ISBLANK` reference to a column elsewhere that should always be populated, so the empty cell highlighting doesn't extend off into infinity.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>Based on your comment, Mac Excel may be lacking the full set of choices available in Windows. In that case, use `=D2="Yes"` and `=D2="No"` to avoid partial match cases.</sub>

Comment: I only used "contain" because in the drop-down there's no "equal to" for some reason... I don't see a solution to my problem with Yellow though. What should I do t highlight everything with Yellow that does not have Yes or No in it?

Comment: If you mean "=NOT(OR(D2="Yes",D2="No")" that just makes all my rows yellow, as you refer to it: "That definitely isn't what you want." and I literally cannot make out which part of your answer refers to what I should do with yellow. You say why it's not working, then you say how to use referencing, which I don't understand how that solves the issue, then you say I should have similar issues with Red and Green (which I don't). So I don't understand which part refers to what I should do with yellow.